# How to recover from KB3001652 update hanging?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I just turned on the only Window machine I have *(need it to run Publisher 2013 - all the other machines are happily running Linux)*, and it prompted to do updates - now its stuck at:

[image: Installing Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (KB3001652)]

I have searched and apparently this is a bad patch and was fixed: [1](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/kb3001652-visual-studio-2010-feb-10-2015-windows/589eee8e-cb6c-424e-b061-b6c6e207bc38), [2](http://www.eightforums.com/windows-updates-activation/61425-update-failure-kb3001652.html), [3 (at the bottom)](http://www.zdnet.com/article/february-2015-patch-tuesday/?tag=nl.e589&s_cid=e589&ttag=e589&ftag=TREc64629f), [4](http://windowsitpro.com/security/first-responders-kb3001652-hangs-computers-never-finishes-installation), etc

What should I do know? The stop installation button does nothing, shutting down will probably means it will continue trying to update for ever and ever instead of shutting down *(and powering off instead of shuting it down properly wil probably muck up my data (again))*, and I don't really know whether I should use the System Restore or not *(it would revert back to old graphics drivers as well which would be annoying)*.

### System Info:

- Windows 7 Pro 64bit (dual booted with Fedora 21)
- Only MS Office program installed Publisher 2013
- Lenovo G570 laptop

EDIT:
Would trying what Cbarnhorst suggests [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/kb3001652-visual-studio-2010-feb-10-2015-windows/589eee8e-cb6c-424e-b061-b6c6e207bc38?page=2) be a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reboot (force the shutdown if necessary, say by using `shutdown -f -r -t 00`), then head to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3001652 and download the fixed version and install it manually.

Reboot if required by that patch, then run Windows Update as usual to do the rest of them.

Comment: Backups are always good. ;)

Comment: It worked - it had to reboot twice, then I installed the package from the site, updated and rebooted. Thanks!